# TCP Networking in Gawk Works for Some Addresses but not Others

Tags: tcp, awk, gawk

I've been fiddling with TCP/IP networking in Gawk and am having a hard time figuring out why it behaves well with some sites but not for others.  I've even tried using HTTP Live Headers in Windows to try and debug what's going on, but to no avail.

The sample Gawk code below (Version 3.1.5) will work fine for the site www.sobell.com but will hang on www.drudgreport.com.

```
BEGIN {
print "Dumping HTML of www.sobell.com"

server = "/inet/tcp/0/www.sobell.com/80"
print "GET http://www.sobell.com" |& server
while ((server |& getline) > 0)
    print $0
close(server)

print "Dumping HTML of www.drudgereport.com"

server = "/inet/tcp/0/www.drudgereport.com/80"
print "GET http://www.drudgereport.com" |& server
while ((server |& getline) > 0)
    print $0
close(server)

}
```

I appreciate any help! Thanks All.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use gawk for this? Why not try Python or Perl.?

Comment: If you haven't, see `info gawkinet`.

Comment: I know Python and Perl can do this, I want to know how to do it in Gawk.  Just because Python and Perl can do it doesn't imply Gawk is broken and useless.

Comment: Dennis thanks, I have read that documentation -frankly, pretty much the only real inet documentation- but will read it again in the hopes that I missed a caveat somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code (and the gawk manual) uses the outdated HTTP/0.9 syntax. Apparently the second server no longer supports this. Important differences:

- The lines must end with "\r\n" instead of plain UNIX newlines.

  You must end your request with an empty line.

  Add a version type (HTTP/1.0 or HTTP/1.1) to the end of the request line.

  Usually the request string does not contain the hostname, this is put on a separate "Host: " line.

The following code works for me:

```
BEGIN {
    ORS = "\r\n"
    server = "/inet/tcp/0/www.drudgereport.com/80"
    print "GET / HTTP/1.1" |& server
    print "Host: www.drudgereport.com" |& server
    print "" |& server
    while ((server |& getline) > 0)
        print $0
    close(server)
}
```

You can find all the gory details in [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945) (1.0) and [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) (1.1).

Comment: Great schot, works perfect.  It is odd the gawkinet I read (for 3.1 and later) mentions the current HTTP being 1.1 but does not write the example code with your approach. Oh well, very glad to have it working!